# Add class to <a> above the current <div>

Tags: jquery

My code in a loop (I have 3 slides in my featured content slider):

```
<a class="featured-image <?php echo "slide-".$i; ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('featured'); ?>
</a>
<div class="featured-about <?php if($active == 1) {echo "active ";} echo "about-".$i; ?>">
    <a class="featured-title"  href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
         <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    </a>
    <span class="excerpt featured-excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></span>
</div>
```

And I need to achieve that when I click on a.featured-about the z-index of correspoding a.featured-image is changed (just e.g. adding addClass e.g. active-image is enough I will do it myself in CSS).

However I guess I need to use onclick like:

```
$('.featured-about').click(function() {
    $(this).prev().addClass('active-image');
});
```

But it is not working.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: .prev()

Get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

Comment: So, if I want to select previous element , in my case <a> how to do that?

Comment: Show the generated HTML, not the PHP.

Comment: Have you put your code within document ready handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [`.prev`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/):

http://jsfiddle.net/gromer/yUHqe/

```
$('.featured-about').click(function() {
    $(this).prevAll('a').addClass('active-image');
});​
```

Edit: Update with `.prevAll` http://jsfiddle.net/gromer/DRV9K/

Comment: Why would `prev('a')` be any different than just `prev()`?

Comment: Just making it more specific.  If the html always was <a></a><div></div>, using just `.prev` would work.

Comment: Wow, I totally read his code as using a different function than `.prev`.  Adding the selector might help, because the generated code might be putting some other element before the clicked `div`.  Will need to see the generated HTML to verify, though.

Comment: @Gromer: How did that work out? `prev('a')` does not work if you have another element in-between the `a` and the `div`. See your own example with another element between them: http://jsfiddle.net/yUHqe/2/ The only way this works is if `a` is the immediate previous element in which case `prev()` would have worked anyway. The only way to get it to work with a random element between `a` and `div` is using `prevAll('a')`: http://jsfiddle.net/yUHqe/3/

Comment: I read the documents differently than they meant.  Change this all to use `.prevAll('a')` and it works.

Comment: @Gromer: +1. Just as a side-note for OP regarding the selector. As per docs: http://api.jquery.com/prev/ specifying a selector in `prev()` causes the preceding element to be filtered by testing whether it matches the selector.` To check beyond the direct preceding sibling, `prevAll()` should be used.

Comment: Yup!  I mistakenly read it as it will go through the previous elements until a match, not _only_ match if the first previous element matched.